# Change Linux Commands

Tags: linux

I'm learning about UNIX security, specifically how it's possible to take advantage of setuid C programs that invoke the `system()` command by creating a custom version of the command called by `system()` that would then do something malicious instead of what was intended. I have created a Linux script for the `cat` command but I'm unsure where to put it and what to do to allow it to be invoked by its filename instead of `./cat`

I think I need to add the directory to `$PATH` but when I tried that I got `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`.

** Update **

So on my machine just to test things out I wrote the C program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  system("ls");
}
```

and I wrote a new ls command

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ran ls command"
```

and made it executable. Then I ran `export PATH="/path/to/command/:$PATH"`.

So I figured out the original problem was that my custom ls command invoked the real ls which was causing a fork problem (I think), but now I want to know about when I'm running this on another machine.

If the vulnerable setuid process is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("cat /some/file");
}
```

and I want to write a custom `cat` command

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/file/
```

will that file be run under the user/group ids of the setuid process or of me because I called invoked the process? I know this isn't quite what I asked originally, but if someone could at least point me to any good resources that would be awesome.

Comment: You're using the right approach and it works when used correctly. I'm guessing your mistake is calling `cat` from your `cat` script, but it's hard to tell when you only provide a casual, high level description of what you did.

Comment: Okay one sec I'm gonna update my question to include more detail.

Comment: @thatotherguy I think I figured out what was wrong originally but I added a follow up question that you could maybe help me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will that file be run under the user/group ids of the setuid process or of me

Interestingly, in this specific case, it will be run as you.

This is because the shebang is `#!/bin/bash` and `bash` has a security feature that will drop suid (based on UID != EUID) when it starts up.

If you run it with `#!/bin/dash` or any other executable, it will run as the suid user.

Comment: So even if the suid process belongs, say to the root user and root group the process it calls will be executed as if I ran it? The reason I ask is because I'm currently working on a challenge that asks you to run process B by a user or group belonging to the group process A (the suid process) belongs to. I was thinking that if I could write a cat command that calls process B from process A it would be like process A called it not I. This is all a little confusing to me though since I'm pretty new to it.

Comment: No, the process will run as root. However, `bash` chooses to drop those root privileges as part of its [exploit mitigation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash).

Comment: Oh okay so the group and user only apply to the process but will be dropped in the rest of the shell?

Comment: Yes. Again, this is a choice that `bash` makes and not something that applies to shells or interpreters in general.